# Posix mmap максимальный вмещаемый размер

Tags: linux, c, posix

Здравствуйте!
Есть задача для обучения пользованию mmap. Для файла требуется определить какой размер в памяти он займет. При этом, если файл в память не вмещается, то нужно выдать максимальный размер, который можно отобразить в память целиком.

Предлагают пользоваться бин поиском, но неужели для этого нет встроенного средства?

Answer (score -1):

Зависит только от объема свободного адресного пространства у вашей программы. То есть, примерно 2^64-1, если машина 64 разрядная.

У меня 18 гигабайт спокойно влезали, при условии, что всего на машине этих гигабайт 8.

Comment: Ну вот вопрос как получить этот размер динамически, чтобы не зависило от платформы и текущего состояние системы

Comment: Маловероятно что вы найдете заранее готовый ответ на данный вопрос. Потому как за адресное пространство вашей программы, ВНЕЗАПНО, отвечает сама ваша программа. Если она написана так, что размещает свои данные без фрагментации, ответ будет найти чуть проще. Но для этого придется перелопатить всю стандартную библиотеку и заменить ее своей.

Практический же смысл такой - пробуем, не влезло - уменьшаем, еще пробуем...

Comment: Вы несколько не правы. Гораздо меньшее число бит используется под виртуальную адресацию на 64-разрядных машинах. Если хотите понять почему, ищите специальные статьи.

Comment: @0andriy я где-то написал, что речь идет об интеле? Без ссылок на статьи вы выглядите бледно.

Comment: Я где-то написал, что речь идёт об x86?! Вы читайте аккуратнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Коллеги, обычный сейчас размер виртуального адреса в 64-bit системе это 40-48 бит.

Comment: @0andriy еще раз, - я нигде не говорил о конкретной физической машине, понимаете?

Comment: А это что: _У меня 18 гигабайт спокойно влезали, при условии, что всего на машине этих гигабайт 8._? Про сферического коня в вакууме, очевидно... Не говоря уже о том, что программу, если это не единственная программа, запущенная на компьютере, нельзя осуждать в отрыве от ОС. А если единственная, то виртуальное адресное пространство теряет всякий смысл, так как MMU настраивается на 1:1 отображение, и на этом всё заканчивается

Comment: В общем, почитайте литературу про MMU и виртуальную память.